# How can I have the click of one button activate 2 divs in different ways with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example:

- Click a button - 1 div flys off the page the other div flys on the page.
- Click the button again  - Same div flys off, other div returns.

I'm brand new to Javascript/JQuery so any help would be great! Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bookBox-1").click(function() {
    $(".main-title").slideUp("slow");
  });

  $(".bookBox-1").click(function() {
    $(".bookDescriptions-kinkyKenny").slideDown();
  });
});
```

```css
.bookDescriptions-kinkyKenny,
.bookDescriptions-eatWhatYoureGiven {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1778px;
  height: 423px;
  top: 144px;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.bookDescription-1,
.bookDescription-2 {
  position: relative;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-title {
  font: 100 125px 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  left: 151px;
}
```

Comment: Does your code not work in some way?  Can you demonstrate and describe the problem?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: I added the code tote post and got the answer i needed. Thanks for commenting though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myfunc1() {
  $(".main-title").slideUp("slow");
  $(".bookDescriptions-kinkyKenny").slideDown();
  $(".bookBox-1").unbind("click", myfunc1);
  $(".bookBox-1").click(myfunc2);
}

function myfunc2() {
  $(".bookDescriptions-kinkyKenny").slideUp("slow");
  $(".main-title").slideDown();
  $(".bookBox-1").unbind("click", myfunc2);
  $(".bookBox-1").click(myfunc1);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bookBox-1").click(myfunc1);
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! .unbind() is what I needed. Thanks a million MiK!